# How to remove spaces between the letters of a "w o r d"

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have texts in which many words have s p a c e s between their letters.
So, I need a script that can remove those spaces.
For example, the string "Hello, this is a  b e a u t i f u l  day" to become "Hello, this is a beautiful day"

I tried something like this:

```
string input="Hello, this is a  b e a u t i f u l  day";
string pattern = @"\b(\w\s\w)+\b";

string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match =>
 {
   string wordWithSpaces = match.Value;
   string wordWithoutSpaces = wordWithSpaces.Replace(" ", "");
   return wordWithoutSpaces;
 });
```

but is not working properly

Comment: How will you distinguish between the word `a` and the letter `a` in `beautiful`?

Comment: I suspect this is about learning how to write regular expressions, but if the goal was to simply remove all spaces, `input.Replace(" ", "")` would be a lot simpler.

Comment: How has this situation arisen that you have text where some parts have no extra spaces and other parts have spaces between characters?

Comment: How would you distinguish `I am a m i d friends` -> `I am amid friends`  from `I am a m i d level developer` -> `I am a mid level developer`? I did notice in your example there is a double space before and after the spaced out word - can we rely on that?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I agree but with note. To preserve real spaces, first two spaces must be replaced with code word/char e.g. `{spc}` then single spaces are removed with blank string and finally `{spc}` become single space.

Comment: How about [replace `\b(\w)\b (?=\b\w\b)|( ) +` with `$1$2`](https://regex101.com/r/AnMYlt/1) (see [.NET demo](https://tio.run/##XY9BS8QwEIXv@RWPsIcU14Jey6Iggge9qOAll6Q7rgMxLZnU7aL722u6FRTnMMPMe3y8aeW87RJN0yAcd3g6SKb3Rv3d6mcac/1IuyG4dDv2iUS4i9Io1QYngkyS1adCKckuc4uPjrd4cBxNdTov4mJIM5ljP2RsoO8ohG6NjDcwBEtzgAeVMRSB8VpmALbuoJv/oBJmCDOp5KOxpOyDa8mc@Gtca@uN3VfWw1xtrLd766svgwpnelZXF6tLXf1Cb8pbXaD6JXGme45kFv6P5aiO0/QN)).

Answer (score 2):

If you can rely on the space-expanded word having 2 spaces each side, you could use that to determine the right position

```
string input = "Hello, this is a  b e a u t i f u l  day";
string pattern = @"\s(\s[\w\s]+\s)\s";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match =>
{
    string wordWithSpaces = match.Value;
    string wordWithoutSpaces = wordWithSpaces.Replace(" ", "");
    return $" {wordWithoutSpaces} ";
});
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bBIoMl

Comment: U put an extra white space after the article "a" ("a beautiful day"). It's not working without.

Comment: @nilsK hence my comment on the question, and the first line of my answer. Those extra spaces were not put by me, but were on the original question!

Answer (score 1):

You try like this :

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "Hello, this is a  b e a u t i f u l  day";
        string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b(\w)(?:\s\w)+\b", match =>
        {
            string matchedText = match.Value;
            string wordWithoutSpaces = Regex.Replace(matchedText, @"\s", "");
            return wordWithoutSpaces;
        });

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Hello, this is a  b e a u t i f u l  day => Hello, this is a  beautiful  day
```

**Explanation :**

**@"\b(\w)(?:\s\w)+\b"** to match words with spaces between their letters.

**(?:\s\w)+** part captures one or more spaces followed by a word character.

Inside the **Regex.Replace** callback, I use **Regex.Replace** again to remove all spaces within the matched word.